# Fail to import semaphore from Vulkan to Cuda

Tags: cuda, interop, semaphore, vulkan

I'm trying to import a Vulkan semaphore for using by CUDA on the windows platform, but always get a cudaErrorInvalidValue error. I can’t figure out what causes the problem.

Considering I have already a HANDLE for the Vulkan semaphore object, the Cuda side is at DLL1 as follows:

```
 void test_createCudaImportSemaphor(HANDLE handle)
{
    cudaExternalSemaphoreHandleDesc externalSemaphoreHandleDesc;
    externalSemaphoreHandleDesc.flags = 0;
    externalSemaphoreHandleDesc.type = cudaExternalSemaphoreHandleTypeOpaqueWin32;
    externalSemaphoreHandleDesc.handle.win32.handle = handle;

    cudaExternalSemaphore_t cudaExternalSemaphore;
    cudaError_t err = cudaImportExternalSemaphore(&cudaExternalSemaphore, &externalSemaphoreHandleDesc);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // err= 1 (cudaErrorInvalidValue )    why ????
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // destory
    err = cudaDestroyExternalSemaphore(cudaExternalSemaphore);
}
```

Testing creation of vulkan semaphore and calling `test_createCudaImportSemaphor` for importing to cuda is in DLL2 as follows:

```
void test_exportVulkanSemphoreToCuda(vk::Device device)
{
    // create semaphore that can be exported (windows platform)
    vk::ExportSemaphoreWin32HandleInfoKHR exportSemaphoreWin32HandleInfoKHR;
    WindowsSecurityAttributes cWinSecurityAttributes; // taken from cuda samples 02_graphics
    exportSemaphoreWin32HandleInfoKHR.pAttributes = &cWinSecurityAttributes;
    exportSemaphoreWin32HandleInfoKHR.dwAccess = DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ | DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_WRITE;

    vk::ExportSemaphoreCreateInfo exportSemaphoreCreateInfo;
    exportSemaphoreCreateInfo.pNext = &exportSemaphoreWin32HandleInfoKHR;
    exportSemaphoreCreateInfo.handleTypes = vk::ExternalSemaphoreHandleTypeFlagBits::eOpaqueWin32;

    vk::SemaphoreCreateInfo semaphoreCreateInfo;
    semaphoreCreateInfo.pNext = &exportSemaphoreCreateInfo;
    vk::UniqueSemaphore upSemaphore = device.createSemaphoreUnique(semaphoreCreateInfo);

    // get semaphore windows handle 
    vk::SemaphoreGetWin32HandleInfoKHR semaphoreGetWin32HandleInfoKHR = {};
    semaphoreGetWin32HandleInfoKHR.semaphore = upSemaphore.get();
    semaphoreGetWin32HandleInfoKHR.handleType = vk::ExternalSemaphoreHandleTypeFlagBits::eOpaqueWin32;
    HANDLE handle = device.getSemaphoreWin32HandleKHR(semaphoreGetWin32HandleInfoKHR);

    // Now try to import sempahore to cuda
    test_createCudaImportSemaphor(handle);

    CloseHandle(handle);
}
```

Comment: memset or fully initialize the `cudaExternalSemaphoreHandleDesc`. You have uninitialized members which are probably holding invalid non-zero values and blowing everything up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @talonmies commented, indeed, the structure cudaExternalSemaphoreHandleDesc is actually not fully initialized with the code shown. The problem is solved when initializing the structure to zero:

```
 cudaExternalSemaphoreHandleDesc externalSemaphoreHandleDesc = {};
```